# Integral with absolute value

Tags: definite-integrals

How to proof that
$$
\frac{1}{2}(t^{2H} + s^{2H} -|t-s|^{2H})= H(2H-1) \int_0^t \int_0^s |u-v|^{2H-2} \, du \, dv
$$
I have trying to usee derivative in the right hand but I have a doubt as to the born of  integration.

Comment: Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You may assume $t \le s$. Then write the inner integral as
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^s |u-v|^{2H-2} du 
    &= \int_0^v (v-u)^{2H-2} \, du + \int_v^s (u-v)^{2H-2}\, du 
\end{align*}
If $H$ is an integer, you can (that seems to be even simpler) use
\[ |v-u|^{2H-2} = (v-u)^{2H-2} \]

Comment: My warm thanks for the clarification.